# ZipArchive::close(): Renaming temporary file failed: Permission denied

Tags: php, file, zip, php-ziparchive

I have this strange error, when I try to delete a file inside a compressed directory :

```
ZipArchive::close(): Renaming temporary file failed: Permission denied in /MyDirectory/myphpscript.php
```

Here is my code :

```
<?php

    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $compressedDirectoryPath = '/Users/Shared/SampleZip.zip';

    $zip = new ZipArchive();

    if ($zip->open($compressedDirectoryPath) === true) { 
        if ($zip->deleteName('SampleZip/samplefile.txt') === true) {
            echo 'File deleted';
        } 
    }

    $zip->close(); // the error is pointing here

?>
```

The `echo` executes successfully and prints `File deleted`. I am running a Mac and the permissions on the compressed directory is `read & write` for all users. What could be the issue?

Comment: Have you shared full code here? If not, are you trying to create or print logs in some text file in your code?

Comment: This is the full code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error tells you, this is a permission problem. Make sure the apache user (`www-data`) has the write permission on the directory where the zip archive is.

After that, your code will work as expected.

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen when you open the output file on server itself and keep it open while trying to run the script again.

Comment: Note: answers that are very brief and/or are questions back to the poster should probably be comments. You only need 50 rep points to comment under a question - could you move this there?